# Compile Error: Arithmetic expressions are not allowed on void types. at line 36 column 26

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

```
@isTest
    private class Testcontactcloud{
        static testMethod void unitTest(){
            Test.StartTest();
            contactcloudcontroller objccc=new contactcloudcontroller();
            Contact c=new Contact();
            c.LastName='indora';
            insert c;            
            Contact con=[select id,AccountId from contact where id=:c.id];

            objccc.getContact();
            system.assert(objccc.clist.size()>0);

            objccc.con.firstname = 'test';
            objccc.con.lastname= 'test';
            objccc.con.email= 'test@test.com';
            objccc.con.phone= '9887305630';
            objccc.con.mailingstate= 'Rajasthan';
            objccc.con.mailingcity= 'ajmer';
            //objccc.save();
            PageReference pageRef = objccc.save();
            system.debug('~'+pageRef);
            System.assertNotEquals(pageRef,null);
            objccc.search();

             objccc.con.lastname= null;
             PageReference pageRef2 = objccc.save();
             system.debug('~'+pageRef2);
             System.assertEquals(pageRef2,null);
             objccc.search();

            objccc.FirstPage();
            system.assertEquals(objccc.OffsetSize,0);

            objccc.Next();
            system.debug('*nextvalue'+objccc.Next());
            system.assert(objccc.OffsetSize>10);

            objccc.Previous();

            objccc.LastPage();

            objccc.getprev();

            objccc.getnxt();

            Test.StopTest();
        }
        static testMethod void unitTest2(){
            Test.StartTest();
            Contact c=new Contact();
            c.LastName='indora';
            insert c;

            contactcloudcontroller objccc=new contactcloudcontroller();
            Contact con=[select id,AccountId from contact where id=:c.id];

            objccc.con.firstname='Test2';
            //objccc.save();
            objccc.OffsetSize=1;
            objccc.QueryLimit=-1;
            objccc.CountTotalRecords = 5;
            objccc.getprev();
            objccc.getnxt();
            Test.StopTest();
        }
          static testMethod void unitTest3(){
            Test.StartTest();
            Contact c=new Contact();
            c.LastName='indora';
            insert c;

            contactcloudcontroller objccc=new contactcloudcontroller();
            Contact con=[select id,AccountId from contact where id=:c.id];
            objccc.con.lastname='test';

            objccc.search();
            System.Assert(objccc.con.lastname!= '');
            Test.StopTest();
        }
        static testMethod void unitTest4(){
            Test.StartTest();
            Contact c=new Contact();
            c.LastName='indora';
            insert c;

            contactcloudcontroller objccc=new contactcloudcontroller();
            Contact con=[select id,AccountId from contact where id=:c.id];
            objccc.con.email='test@test.com';

            objccc.search();
            Test.StopTest();
        }

        static testMethod void unitTest5(){
            Test.StartTest();
            Contact c=new Contact();
            c.LastName='indora';
            insert c;
            contactcloudcontroller objccc=new contactcloudcontroller();
            Contact con=[select id,AccountId from contact where id=:c.id];
            objccc.con.phone='878999999';

            objccc.search();
            Test.StopTest();
        }
        static testMethod void unitTest6(){
            Test.StartTest();
            Contact c=new Contact();
            c.LastName='indora';
            insert c;

            contactcloudcontroller objccc=new contactcloudcontroller();
            Contact con=[select id,AccountId from contact where id=:c.id];
            objccc.con.MailingState='rajasthan';

            objccc.search();
            Test.StopTest();
        }
        static testMethod void unitTest7(){
            Test.StartTest();

            Contact c=new Contact();
            c.LastName='indora';
            insert c;

            contactcloudcontroller objccc=new contactcloudcontroller();
            Contact con=[select id,AccountId from contact where id=:c.id];
            objccc.con.MailingCity='ajmer';

            objccc.search();
            Test.StopTest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does objccc.Next() return?

Comment: Next is void type method its return nothing

Comment: That is your issue then. When you do `system.debug('*nextvalue'+objccc.Next());` , you're concatenating a string and a void

Answer (score 2):

In your test class, replace your old line 36:

```
system.debug('*nextvalue'+objccc.Next());
```

with this:

```
system.debug('*nextvalue');
```

This should make the exception go away and your unit tests should compile.

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to concatenate a string with a void value (the return value of `objccc.Next()`).

Comment: then what should i do @mkorman

Comment: I mentioned it in my answer above, please read it carefully :)

Comment: i want to check my public void Next() into test class using assert() method than what i do?

Comment: I've edited my response for more clarity. Your question does not say much, and only mentions a compile error. I think my answer explains how to make the compile error go away, so that your tests can run. To help you on how to test your 'Next()' method, I suggest you create a new question, asking clearly what you want, and posting both the production and the test classes.